# Pivot table not working, pivot returning NULLs

Tags: sql, pivot

Could someone please help with the following PIVOT table?

I want to get a single row for each product, with the current trade price, then 5 columns giving the historical trade prices side by side.

e.g

ProductID Trade T1    T2    T3     T4     T5

12345     100   99.44 96.44 102.45 101.12 99.99

etc

Current code, which is returning NULL in each of the pivoted columns

```
SELECT ProductID,ProductTradePrice AS Trade, 
 [0], [1], [2], [3], [4]
FROM
(
    SELECT ChangeLogID, p.ProductID , ProductName, ProductTradePrice,
        CONVERT(decimal(18,2),ChangeLogOldValue) AS ChangeLogOldValue 
    FROM tblProduct p 
        INNER JOIN tblChangeLog cl ON p.ProductID = cl.ProductID
    WHERE PrimarySupplierNumber = 7
    AND ChangeLogItemChanged = 'ProductTradePrice'

) S
PIVOT
(
AVG(ChangeLogOldValue)
FOR ChangeLogID IN ([0], [1], [2], [3], [4])
) AS PivotTable;
```

[image]

[image]

Comment: Please describe exactly what is in the table you are starting with and exactly what you want the outcome to look like

Comment: I don't see any `ChangeLogID` with value 0 or 1 or 2 or 3 or 4.  So it returns `null`.  I think it behaves correctly.